# Home partition taking up too much space?

Tags: partition

I've recently had to reinstall YouCompleteMe on a VM, and when I'm installing it, I get that I'm running out of hard drive space. It installed fine the first time around, but now when some of the downloaded material is extracted with tar, I get "No space left on device"... etc.

So I went and checked `df` and got the following:

```
Filesystem           1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/web-root   2479472 2026608    326912  87% /
udev                     10240       0     10240   0% /dev
tmpfs                    50892     284     50608   1% /run
tmpfs                     5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                   101760       0    101760   0% /run/shm
/dev/sda1               233191   26181    194569  12% /boot
/dev/mapper/web-home   5225040  337608   4622012   7% /home
```

I can't tell if anything is particularly bad, but it seems very weird to me that my home partition has so much space while my root partition is running empty.

Is there something I'm doing / I've done wrong?

Comment: did you try running a `du` on /home to see which folder is taking up so much space? something like `sudo du -c /home | sort -nr` will give you a nice reverse ordered list of folder sizes in bytes and help track down the culprit.

Comment: Most of the stuff is the newly-downloaded YouCompleteMe, but it's not that big-- `194804  /home/web/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe`

Comment: the filesystem *shouldn't* lie to you, does the total of the `du` match the total used in `df`?

Comment: `196196  total` is what's listed.

Comment: if you run `lsof` are there many open files in /home? maybe there is a zombie process that is holding files open there which will cause `df` to give a higher used value.

Comment: I've just rebooted the machine, so I don't think it'd be a zombie process... though I'm not familiar with what to look for in `lsof`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22234/discussion-between-son-of-fire-and-user2899162).

Comment: I would suggest posting more details about what you do to fix the issue, and answer your own question if you find out. i will upvote.